Varistor and Fuse Failures in Control Panel During Power Failures - Seeking Advice on Enhanced Protection
Question:
I'm facing a recurring issue with our control panels used for firefighting and fire alarm systems. During power failures, the varistors, responsible for overvoltage and undervoltage protection, often get burned out, which subsequently affects the fuses and the overall protection circuit.
Panel Specifications:
Single Phase Supply
220VAC
50 Hz
Maximum variation: ± 5%
Issue Details:
There is a power issue occurring at the site. All panels connected to the earth bar have their L and PE varistors burned out, while other panels at the same site and time, with no earth connection, have their NTC/current limiters burned, but not the varistors.
Varistor Configuration:
One varistor between L and N
One varistor between L and PE
One varistor between N and PE
Diagnostics:
Frequent voltage spikes and surges
Overvoltage incidents causing varistors to engage and fail
Fuses blowing as a secondary protective measure
We have considered using an RCBO - 1 P - 30mA to protect our equipment. However, we are unsure if this solution will adequately protect against issues related to live (L), neutral (N), and protective earth (PE) conductors, as my understanding is that the RCBO primarily protects against leakage current to prevent electric shock, rather than protecting equipment from failures caused by other equipment.
Specific Questions:
Will the RCBO be sufficient to protect our control panels from such power issues?
Are there additional or alternative protection devices or measures you would recommend to enhance the reliability and protection of our panels?
Has anyone faced similar issues, and what solutions were implemented to prevent such failures?
Any advice or recommendations from those who have faced similar issues or have expertise in this area would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It sounds like the neutral in the 3phase distribution gets interrupted, thus single phase circuits get phase to phase voltages that destroy the varistors.  I’d suggest an in depth review of the electrical system on site. My guess is that the neutral is maybe switched via contactors or suchlike if there is a genset.

Shouldn't this affect the varistor between line and neutral, not the one between line and PE., most of the failed panels have L and PE varistor burned with the fuse   and other 2 varistors between L and N , N and PE intact.  Would a voltage leackage on the earth bus bar cause this particular varistor to burnout ?

Strange things can happen when you lose a neutral - it depends on the balance of the active loads. Nevertheless, something is NQR ( not quite right) and some investigation is needed. Yes, the earth might be faulty, so that is usually easier to test as it would be extremely unlikely that an earth is ever switched, so a simple resistance test should  identify a problem.

RCBOs aren't designed to detect overvoltage.  You need to work out what the underlying problem is.  And I also suspect it's a faulty neutral.

Reverting back after a site visit, the site has IT earthing system with floating earth.
